# Issue with Android Wear Message API

Tags: messaging, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I m trying to use the new android wear comms API, specifically the Message API to which end I have an Activity plus a service in my watch application and an Activity as the test app in the phone.

I have comms working fine in both directions and I can start up my Watch Activity via the comms by sending messages from the Phone app which also works fine except for a single issue which only occurs immediately after a reboot of the watch hardware:

If I start my Watch app via a comms message call immediately after a reboot without first running a Watch App Activity then the message reply returned from the Watch is lost and not seen by the Phone App.

If I run an Activity in the Watch App after the reboot and before initiating comms from the Phone App then the comms messages work fine, even if I close the Watch Activity before sending any messages.

My WearableListenerService code on the Watch side looks like the following (much abbreviated)

```
public class MyClass extends WearableListenerService
                        implements MessageApi.MessageListener,
                                   ConnectionCallbacks,
                                   OnConnectionFailedListener
{

...

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                                          .addApi(Wearable.API)
                                          .build();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

   super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
    int result = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    return result;
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent)
{
    comms.handleReceivedMessage (messageEvent);
}

public final void txReply(String txMessage, String nodeId)
{
    Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, 
                                    nodeId,
                                    MESSAGE_RECEIVED_PATH, 
                                    txMessage.getBytes());
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)
{
    Wearable.MessageApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

My comms.handleReceivedMessage() function directly calls the txReply() function above and I have verified the data is correct using LogCat.

I'd be extremely grateful for any pointers as to what I may be missing which prevents my first Watch App message from being received by the Phone App.  Again, this behavious only occurs immediately after a reboot iff the Watch App Activity has not been run before a message is received.

--EDIT-- @ Murphy:

Well, I looked at your code and it seems almost the same as what I already have, in fact I have  the following in place of your call :

```
NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).await();
for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) 
{
    // Send message and wait for result
    SendMessageResult result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, 
                                                               node.getId(),
                                                               MESSAGE_RECEIVED_PATH, 
                                                               txm.getBytes()).await();
}
```

So the differences are not significant in respect of comms from the Watch getting lost, but thanks anyway for your help.

Regards,

Comment: Did anyone solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to addListener for message API and implement MessageApi.MessageListener since WearableListenerService does it for you, you can just override method onMessageReceived.

As for the problem, you should ensure google api is connected (as I mention above, WearableListenerService is managed by the system, so you can receive a message earlier than your api client is connected):

```
public final void txReply(String txMessage, String nodeId)
{
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) 
    {
            ConnectionResult connectionResult 
                         = mGoogleApiClient.blockingConnect(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (!connectionResult.isSuccess()) {
                //log or show error
                return;
            }
    }
    Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, 
                                nodeId,
                                MESSAGE_RECEIVED_PATH, 
                                txMessage.getBytes());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the `googleApiClient` connected does not ensure you have a connection with your `Wear`.

I recommend you to check on the phone side the `Wear` connection before sending the `Message`:

```
Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(getGoogleApiClient()).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult getConnectedNodesResult) {
        boolean isPeerConnected = getConnectedNodesResult.getNodes().size() > 0;
}});
```

Edit:
If it's not connected, then I you can send when it's connecting using:

```
Wearable.NodeApi.addListener(getGoogleApiClient(), new NodeApi.NodeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPeerConnected(Node node) {
        // TODO send message
    }

    @Override
    public void onPeerDisconnected(Node node) {

    }
})
```

Comment: Hi Murphy, thanks for your reply.  I can try what you suggest, but what should I do if there is no connection ?  Just spin for a few milliseconds and try again ?

Comment: Hi Murphy,  I added an EDIt at the foot of my question showing what I already have.  It is the same as yours in effect so I don't think that can be the problem, but thanks anyway for your help,

Comment: Ok, do you know if it actually sends the message or skips because there's no connection? Can you add a Log and test? If it's not connected I recommend you waiting for the connection, sending the message using Wearable.NodeApi.addListener->onPeerConnected(). I added it to my answer too.

Comment: Hi Murphy, do you mean on the phone ?  I am sure the Phone is sending the message but I cannot say whether the Watch is receiving it and failing to transmit the reply or failing to receive the message in the first place.  This is because I cannot replicate the issue when the phone is placed in its cradle (whether or not I am debugging the phone doesn't matter, the error does not occur when the phone is in the cradle).  I tried creating a non-debug signed version of Phone and Watch apps to see if it was something in the debugger but my signed apps show the same issue.  Thanks,

Comment: I was having the issue too. My Wear is connected an the getConnectedNodes() clearly mentions it too. But when I send the message from the phone, occasionally, it still gets lost on its way, and never reaches the watch.